# PHP odbc_prepare WHERE field IN ($LIST) - (Progress OpenEdge 10.2A)

Tags: php, sql, odbc, openedge

I am trying to write a query using the odbc_prepare and odbc_execute statements like so:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE names IN (?) AND age < ?';
$names = "Joe, John, Billy";
$age = 21;
$result = odbc_prepare($this->connection, $query);
odbc_execute($query, array($names, $age));
```

Of course for some reason this isn't working and I have tried several variations on my $names variable formatting.  Any help would be appreciated as I haven't been able to find any examples of a query that uses odbc_prepare and a WHERE IN clause.

I am connecting to a Progress database using an OpenEdge 10.2A odbc driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to let everyone in the future know what I came up with for this particular problem:

```
$names = array("Joe","John","Billy");

$queryVars = array();
foreach($names AS $name){
    $queryVars[] = $name;
}

$paramBind = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($names), '?'));
$query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE names IN ('.$paramBind.')';

odbc_execute($query, $queryVars);
```

Hope someone else finds this useful

Comment: concatenating text into queries makes the code prone to sql injection

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use [array()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in a weird way.

Try doing something like:

```
$names = array("Joe", "John", "Billy");
foreach($names as $name)
{   
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE names IN (?)'
    $result = odbc_prepare($this->connection, $name);
    odbc_execute($query, $name);
}
```

Here is also some more information on [odbc_prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-prepare.php)

Comment: If I seperate it as you have suggested that would indicate that I am passing 3 variables to it as opposed to just one. I have read the docs and my understanding was that you need to pass all variables into an array one at a time, so If you had a query that had WHERE names = ? AND age < ? you could pass array("Joe", "21") to find all Joe's under 21.

Comment: So you would like to execute the statement three separate times then?

Comment: Perhaps a better example is something like this:
`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE names IN (?) AND age < ?`

Comment: using a loop to separate my values and query each one individually is poor design, if I have 100 names I want to pick out that means 100 queries I need to run. Definitely not what I want to do.

Comment: You need to clarify more of what you are looking for. Are you looking to have your query end up like SELECT * FROM table WHERE names IN ('bob', 'greg', 'sam') --- or are you looking for --- SELECT * FROM table WHERE names IN ('bob'), SELECT * FROM table WHERE names IN ('greg')?

Comment: Also, what database platform are you connecting to. You need to supply this information.

Comment: I'm not sure where you came to the idea I wanted to set up 3 queries, if that were the case I would never use an IN statement i'd just use =.  I am connecting to a Progress database using an OpenEdge 10.2A odbc driver.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from the manual I think it should look like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE names IN (?)'
$names = array("Joe", "John", "Billy");
$result = odbc_prepare($this->connection, $query);
odbc_execute($query, array(implode(',', $names));
```

This gives a array with 1 element, because there is 1 parameter requested. 
The element contains a string `'Joe, John, Billy'` and that is the correct value for the `IN`  clause.

Comment: you can't explode an array last I knew.

Comment: still no dice. I've even gone as far as setting up $names = "'Joe', 'John', 'Billy'"; and it hasn't worked, almost as if the bind doesn't support IN clauses or something.

Comment: I know from mysql that it not supports parameters into functions. Is IN a function?

Comment: This answer will not work for Progress OpenEdge. Please read last sentence in question where it defines environment. This answer contains logic that is relevant to MySQL not Progress.